# Dynamic query where clause in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have this query

```
$res = propertyDetail::find()
    ->joinWith('propertyImages')
    ->all();

$res = $res->where(['pkPropertyIDPrimary' => 1]);
```

I receive this error:

> Call to a member function where() on array

This query contains a property Image and property detail records. Now I want to add a where clause in this dynamic.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this way,

```
$res =  propertyDetail::find()
        ->joinWith('propertyImages');

$res = $res->where(['pkPropertyIDPrimary' => 1])->all();
```